# React useState is not correctly updating the state of my child component props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asynchronous, use-effect, use-state

I spent days trying to figure out what's wrong with my code and in doing so, tried multiple solutions/suggestions but no luck.

**UPDATE**
Reproduced the issue in the following codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-pond-u130qs?file=/src/selectTracker.tsx

**Summary of the issue**
I have a parent component with 2 children. The first child is responsible for capturing user's selection from a Select and invoking a setState wrapper in the parent. The parent will then pass the user's selection as props to the second child which will use it to fetch data from an API and then display it in a table. The issue is that , the table will not re-render when the state changes but only when there is another selection. Meaning, I select value A, nothing happens, then I select value B , then the table renders data based on value A. I know React states handling is asynchronous but that should not explain the bug I'm facing. Happy to hear your suggestions/potential fixes.

**Parent Component**

```js
const MainComponent = () => {
  const [trackerSetup, setTrackerSetup] = useState<TrackerSetup>();

  return (
    <>
      <Container maxWidth="lg">
        <Grid
          direction="row"
          container
          alignItems="center"
          justifyContent="center"
          spacing={2}
          marginTop={5}
        >
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <AddTrackerSetupComponent />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <SelectTrackerSetupComponent setTrackerSetup={setTrackerSetup} />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>

        {trackerSetup ? (
          <TrackerTableComponent trackerSetup={trackerSetup} />
        ) : (
          <span>Select a tracker setup</span>
        )}
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};

export default MainComponent;
```

**Child 1**

```js
interface SelectTrackerSetupComponentProps {
  setTrackerSetup: any;
}

const SelectTrackerSetupComponent = (
  props: SelectTrackerSetupComponentProps
) => {
  const [existingTrackerSetups, setExistingTrackerSetups] =
    useState<TrackerSetup[]>();
  const [
    selectedExistingTrackerSetupIndex,
    setSelectedExistingTrackerSetupIndex,
  ] = useState(0);

  useMemo(() => {
    const existingSetups = JSON.parse(
      localStorage.getItem("trackerSetup")!
    ) as TrackerSetup[];
    setExistingTrackerSetups(existingSetups);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {existingTrackerSetups && existingTrackerSetups.length > 0 ? (
        <FormControl fullWidth>
          <InputLabel id="existingSetups">Select an Existing Setup</InputLabel>
          <Select
            labelId="existingSetups"
            id="existingSetups-select"
            label="Existing Setups"
            value={selectedExistingTrackerSetupIndex}
            onChange={(e) => {
              setSelectedExistingTrackerSetupIndex(Number(e.target.value));
              props.setTrackerSetup(
                existingTrackerSetups[Number(e.target.value)]
              );
            }}
          >
            {existingTrackerSetups.map((trackerSetup: TrackerSetup, index) => {
              return (
                <MenuItem key={trackerSetup.name} value={index}>
                  {trackerSetup.name}
                </MenuItem>
              );
            })}
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
      ) : (
        <span>Loading..</span>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default SelectTrackerSetupComponent;
```

**Child 2**

```js
interface TrackerTableComponentProps {
  trackerSetup: TrackerSetup;
}

const TrackerTableComponent = (props: TrackerTableComponentProps) => {
  const [trackers, setTrackers] = useState<Tracker[]>();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadTrackerData = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      const fetchedTrackers = await getTrackerObject(
        props.trackerSetup.trackers
      );
      console.log("Displaying the following trackers ", fetchedTrackers);
      setTrackers(fetchedTrackers);
    };
    loadTrackerData();
    setLoading(false);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {!loading ? (
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
          <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }} aria-label="simple table">
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell>Tracker ID</TableCell>
                <TableCell>FW version</TableCell>
                <TableCell>battery level</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Actions</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              {trackers &&
                trackers.map((tracker: Tracker) => {
                  console.log("Table: displaying tracker ", tracker);
                  return (
                    <TableRow
                      key={tracker.id}
                      sx={{ "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": { border: 0 } }}
                    >
                      <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                        {tracker.id}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell>{tracker.fwVersion}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>{tracker.batteryLevel.toString()} %</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>
                        <Button
                          variant="contained"
                          color="success"
                          size="small"
                        >
                          Update FW
                        </Button>
                      </TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  );
                })}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
      ) : (
        <span>Loading...</span>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default TrackerTableComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your issue with codesandbox. There was a small and simple warning inside `TrackerTableComponent: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props.trackerSetup.trackers'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.` within your useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const loadTrackerData = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const fetchedTrackers = await getTrackerObject(
      props.trackerSetup.trackers
    );
    console.log("Displaying the following trackers ", fetchedTrackers);
    setTrackers(fetchedTrackers);
  };
  loadTrackerData();
  setLoading(false);
}, []); // <- Here
```

If you change it to `[props.trackerSetup.trackers]` table will reflect changes as expected. But. In your `SelectTrackerSetupComponentProps` you are loading items from localstorage and setting them to `setExistingTrackerSetups`, but you also have a selectedIndex there and you component renders with selected 0 item loaded. But you didnt call the passed `props.setTrackerSetup` to make the table render the actual data when initially loaded. So changes to `SelectTrackerSetupComponent`:

Not important but still better than "any" type

```
interface SelectTrackerSetupComponentProps {
  setTrackerSetup: React.Dispatch<SetStateAction<TrackerSetup>>;
}
```

Extracted method from "props" object, i just prefer to extract everything from passed props.

```
const { setTrackerSetup } = props;
```

Changed your useMemo to useEffect due to logically it suits better

```
useEffect(() => {

  // change it back, i used dummy data from constant
  const existingSetups =
    /*JSON.parse(
    localStorage.getItem("trackerSetup")!
  ) as TrackerSetup[];*/
    TRACKER_SETUPS;

  setExistingTrackerSetups(existingSetups);
  // Added to prevent future possible bugs
  setSelectedExistingTrackerSetupIndex(0); 
  // Added to tell parent component that actual item is now selected
  setTrackerSetup(existingSetups[0]);
}, [setTrackerSetup]);
```

[image: Edit twilight-star-3w8vf2]

Update: After codesandbox provided the root issue of errors was found:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    let list: Tracker[] = [];
    // Error is just below...
    props.trackerSetup.trackers.forEach(async (tracker) => {
      const fetchedTracker = await getMockData();
      console.log(fetchedTracker);
      list.push({
        id: "tracker ID",
        fwVersion: fetchedTracker.data.fw_version,
        batteryLevel: fetchedTracker.data.battery_level
      });
    });
    setTrackers(list);
    setLoading(false);
  };
  fetchData();
}, []);
```

`props.trackerSetup.trackers.forEach(async (tracker) => {` will not work in that way.

Correct code:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    // CHANGE: Foreach is not working nice with async.
    // Converting to promises instead.
    const promises = props.trackerSetup.trackers.map(async (tracker) => {
      const fetchedTracker = await getMockData();
      console.log(fetchedTracker);
      const result: Tracker = {
        // CHANGE: That will cause a duplicate key error. Changed to random
        id: (Math.random() * (10000 - 1) + 1).toString(),
        fwVersion: fetchedTracker.data.fw_version,
        batteryLevel: fetchedTracker.data.battery_level
      };
      return result;
    });
    const list = await Promise.all(promises);
    setTrackers(list);
    setLoading(false);
  };
  fetchData();
  // CHANGE: You didnt set needed item in depsArray as i described in answer
  // React will not re-execute this hook on trackers changed without it
}, [props.trackerSetup.trackers]);
```

Comment: I tried your suggestions but unfortunately the outcome is the same. I've attached a screenshot here https://ibb.co/12QLfY6 where I have used react tools add-on in Chrome to check the current state values and my array of trackers state was correctly set but for whatever reason the table will only render it once I select another setup from the Select dropdown. Driving me crazy mate..

Comment: @anassarakia Sorry, but i have no idea how to reproduce your issue, i tried and wrote what i figured out of it, if by any chance you can provide codesandbox or any other way to reproduce the issue - we will be able to help. Also, do not forget to update the code in your question to include most recent changes, maybe someone will find an solution

Comment: @anassarakia Just a note, react will not render or re-render when object to render is mutated, not "replaced" by new one, if reference to object is the same but object itself is mutated - react will not detect that, i dont see the full picture so sorry

Comment: I created a codesandbox with mock endpoint to accurately reproduce the issue. You can find it here https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-pond-u130qs?file=/src/selectTracker.tsx
I will also update the original post with codesandbox

Comment: @anassarakia Your root issue was due to .forEach(async....) which will not work. Changed to promises, also added what i initially wrote in my answer: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-worker-104xvk?file=/src/selectTracker.tsx

Comment: tried your promises suggestion and worked just fine. I appreciate your time, you just saved me a lot of headaches :). Thanks

Comment: @anassarakia no worries, that kind of the issues is one of the most popular. Btw do not forget to accept answers so your question will not appear in stackoverflow's questions without accepted answer list, also, +reputation for me :)